# Can we print a word on pressing a key on android keyboard?

Tags: java, android

I have a doubt that whether we can print a word on pressing a single key on the keyboard.

For example, consider a key named as **hi**, upon pressing it, the word **hi** has to be displayed on the screen. Whether it is possible or not?
If it is possible, kindly suggest me a solution. :)

Comment: Of course, you can do that. Make a simple keyboard with keys you want and fetch the content of the key upon a press or map the keys with an id and its value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have tried it but it doesn't working.. Can u please give me an example for it..?